# Invalid `Podfile` file: 767: unexpected token at ''

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I am trying to run my IOS app with react native, but I need to update my Pods. so I run on terminal:

```
cd iOS && pod install
```

But I get this error on the title

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/my-user/Documents/Test/my-app/ios/undefined'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 767: unexpected token at ''.
#  from /Users/my-user/Documents/Test/my-app/ios/Podfile:12
#  -------------------------------------------
#  
>    use_native_modules!
#  end
#  -------------------------------------------
```

What should I Do?

My Podfile is as follow

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'


target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp

  use_native_modules!
end
```

and my package.json file uses this dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
  "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^3.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.3.0",
  "@sentry/react-native": "3.4.3",
  "@virgilsecurity/e3kit": "^0.7.0-beta.2",
  "@virgilsecurity/key-storage-rn": "^0.2.1",
  "appcenter-cli": "^2.1.2",
  "moment": "2.29.3",
  "react": "16.9.0",
  "react-native": "0.61.3",
  "react-native-calendars": "1.259.0",
  "react-native-code-push": "6.0.0",
  "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
  "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
  "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
  "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
  "react-native-fs": "^2.14.1",
  "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.13.0",
  "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.2",
  "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
  "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.1",
  "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
  "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
  "react-native-twilio-video-webrtc": "^2.0.0",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
  "react-native-virgil-crypto": "^0.6.1",
  "react-native-webview": "^7.4.1",
  "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
  "react-router": "^5.1.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
  "react-router-native": "^5.1.2",
  "realm": "6.0.3",
  "redux": "^4.2.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
},
```

if I take use_native_modules! out of the code, it works properly. But with him it doesn't

Comment: It happened in React Native 0.69.0. I have also followed the proper migration guidelines but it didn't work. I am also waiting for the resolution.

Comment: hey @IOSDev , in my case I am using "react-native": "0.61.3",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally!!! To install my pods, normally, I just needed to do 3 things.

1- Remove the package **@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios** from package.json

2- on terminal, access the main app folder and update changes on node_modules

```
yarn
```

3- Access iOS page and install the pods

```
cd ios && pod install
```

Comment: I didn't have cli-platform-ios, but `yarn install && pod install` did it for me

Comment: in my package.json, he was the problem

Answer (score 11):

I just deleted node_modules, and then ran `npm i` and then ran `pod install` to solve the error

Comment: in my case, i needed to remove @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios

Comment: this worked on my end

Comment: This worked in my case, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this issue on my machine by disabling VS Code's debugger Auto Attach feature. The feature was causing Node to spew extra console output, which the `native_modules.rb` file could not parse.

This error could be caused from any number of local configuration issues. So my solution may not work for you. If disabling VS Code Auto Attach doesn't solve it for you, here is how you can investigate more:

`unexpected token at ''` is a *JavaScript* error. If you go to the Ruby file where the error originates (usually `../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules.rb`), you can see that it is trying to open some JS files from your node_modules using Node. In your terminal, `cd` to the location of the `native_modules.rb` file and try to execute the Node commands on your terminal - you may get more clues about what is going on on your system. Good luck.

Comment: it fixed when i removed cli-platform-ios, there was no need for my code, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I kept using the integrated terminal and it failed. I used a separate Bash terminal and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I was running `pod install` in VSCode and it didn't work, turning the `Debug: Toggle Auto Attach` to off worked for me. Good find, can't believe it is due to parsing output issue.. thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! I spent too many hours trying to fix it and your answer fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

You should check your **npm version**, I was trying to run pod install with an **old npm version (6.14.18)**, then I switched to a **newer npm version (18.18.0)** and it worked! :).

**Note:** To be able to successfully manage multiple Node versions on your macOS, I recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), a Node Version Manager. With this little fella, you can easily jump from one Node version to another.
You can also install multiple versions and select one specific version for each project that you have.

Comment: This worked in my case. And if you're wondering how to switch the node version, you can install and use nvm (node version manager) and for example in your project directory use this command 'nvm use node 18' (need to have node 18 installed)

Comment: @AwabIjaz, I've edited my post and added more information about nvm. :)

Comment: Yes this is correct, i also faced this and resolved with upgrade node version

Answer (score 4):

I was successful when I did "yarn install" again

Comment: what about your package.json configuration?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it happened when I upgraded my project react-native version to `0.72.7` and remove the `package="..."` in root `<manifest >` of `main/Android Manifest.xml`.

Not sure why react-native is getting package name from Android to iOS podfile. But just re-add the `package="..."` fixed the issue.

Comment: same resolution for me

Answer (score 2):

I tried several times to delete node_modules and `npm i && cd ios && pod install`. All of them failed.

Here is how I make it work.

1. I removed package-lock.json and node_modules.
2. I deleted the config in `react-native.config.js` because there is a config `automaticPodsInstallation: true`. I changed it to false and it does not work, so I just deleted this attribute. I think it is the main reason of my installation failure. When I use `--verbose` to install it, it shows:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unexpected token at 'Config Validation Error: "project.ios.automaticPodsInstallation" is not allowed
```

3.Run `yarn`, `cd ios && pod install`

It works for me.

Comment: Thank You!!! you can comment the line instead of deleting the file.

Comment: Work like charm

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was **node 14**. Removing package-lock.json and node_moduled didn't work

I switched to **node 20**, remove package-lock.json and node_module.
Now the iOS build is working

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade node version.
i solved this error with update node version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different but similar issue, I was facing the following error:

```
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Invalid `Podfile` file: 809: unexpected token at ''.
```

My issue was that I was running Node through nvm for management of different node versions with different projects.

My system node version was quite old, and running `pod install` with my system node version was failing with this error.

I simply needed to use `nvm list` to see the different node I had installed, and then `nvm use vx.x.x` to select the more updated version that I wanted to use. Once I had my terminal using the more recent version of node, then running `pod install` worked for me.