Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file - Error pod install
I am having an issue when running the pod install command since I updated the operating system to the latest version and Xcode to 15.4.
Error:

[!] Invalid Podfile file: cannot load such file -- /Users/zzz/Documents/GitHub/project/apps/mobile/node_modules/@nrwl/react-native/nx_post_install.

This project uses a mono-repo, so at the root of the project, I have this 'package.json':
  "private": true,"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.16",
"@mui/material": "^5.10.16",
"@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.10.16",
"@native-base/icons": "^0.0.11",
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.4",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.4.0",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
"@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.12",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"fast-copy": "^2.1.3",
"i18next": "^20.4.0",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"json-patch": "^0.7.0",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.18",
"lodash.isplainobject": "^4.0.6",
"luxon": "^3.2.1",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"native-base": "^3.4.5",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-i18next": "^11.11.4",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-native-beacons-manager": "https://github.com/Hamilton-Robson/react-native-beacons-manager.git",
"react-native-big-calendar": "^4.6.0",
"react-native-biometrics": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-ble-manager": "^11.1.0",
"react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^3.0.7",
"react-native-calendar-events": "^2.2.0",
"react-native-calendar-picker": "^7.1.4",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1301.0",
"react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.6",
"react-native-device-info": "^10.13.2",
"react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
"react-native-localize": "^3.0.2",
"react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
"react-native-notifications": "^4.3.1",
"react-native-otp-textinput": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-paper": "^5.1.4",
"react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-pin-view": "^3.0.2",
"react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
"react-native-rsa-native": "^2.0.5",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
"react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
"react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
"react-native-table": "^1.0.1",
"react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
"react-native-uuid-generator": "^6.1.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
"regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
"styled-components": "^5.3.6",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zustand": "^3.7.2" },"devDependencies": {
"@nrwl/cli": "14.4.3",
"@nrwl/detox": "14.4.3",
"@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.4.3",
"@nrwl/jest": "14.4.3",
"@nrwl/linter": "14.4.3",
"@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
"@nrwl/react": "14.4.3",
"@nrwl/react-native": "^14.4.3",
"@nrwl/web": "14.4.3",
"@nrwl/workspace": "14.4.3",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.6",
"@react-native-community/cli": "7.0.3",
"@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "7.0.1",
"@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "7.0.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
"@testing-library/jest-native": "4.0.5",
"@testing-library/react": "13.3.0",
"@testing-library/react-native": "9.1.0",
"@types/jest": "27.4.1",
"@types/json-patch": "^0.0.30",
"@types/lodash.isplainobject": "^4.0.6",
"@types/node": "16.11.7",
"@types/react": "18.0.14",
"@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
"@types/react-native": "0.67.8",
"@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.29.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.29.0",
"babel-jest": "27.5.1",
"detox": "19.7.1",
"eslint": "~8.15.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.30.1",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
"jest": "27.5.1",
"jest-circus": "27.5.1",
"jest-react-native": "18.0.0",
"metro": "0.71.1",
"metro-babel-register": "0.71.1",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.71.1",
"metro-resolver": "0.71.1",
"nx": "14.4.3",
"prettier": "^2.6.2",
"react-native-config": "1.4.6",
"react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.1.0",
"react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
"ts-jest": "27.1.4",
"ts-node": "~10.8.0",
"typescript": "~4.7.2"}

Package.Json inside apps/mobile:
{"name": "mobile","version": "0.0.1","private": true,"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-native": "*",
"@testing-library/react-native": "*",
"react": "*",
"react-native": "*",
"react-native-config": "*",
"react-native-svg": "*",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "*",
"i18next": "*",
"react-i18next": "*",
"@react-navigation/native": "*",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "*",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "*",
"styled-components": "*",
"native-base": "*",
"react-native-screens": "*",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "*",
"react-native-vector-icons": "*",
"lodash.isplainobject": "*",
"axios": "*",
"fast-copy": "*",
"json-patch": "*",
"react-native-flash-message": "*",
"zustand": "*",
"react-native-device-info": "*",
"react-native-rsa-native": "*",
"react-native-uuid-generator": "*",
"react-native-render-html": "*",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "*",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "*",
"react-native-notifications": "*",
"react-native-pin-view": "*",
"react-native-otp-textinput": "*",
"moment": "*",
"react-native-date-picker": "*",
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "*",
"react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "*",
"react-native-calendars": "*",
"luxon": "*",
"intl": "*",
"react-native-calendar-events": "*",
"react-native-country-picker-modal": "*",
"react-native-phone-number-input": "*",
"libphonenumber-js": "*",
"react-native-swipe-list-view": "*",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "*",
"react-native-paper": "*",
"react-native-beacons-manager": "*",
"react-native-calendar-picker": "*",
"react-native-localize": "*",
"react-native-modal": "*",
"react-native-big-calendar": "*",
"@eabdullazyanov/react-native-sms-user-consent": "*",
"react-native-biometrics": "*",
"react-native-table": "*",
"react-native-table-component": "*",
"react-native-ble-manager": "*",
"react-native-collapsible": "*"}}

Podfile:


require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/@nrwl/react-native/nx_post_install'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

abstract_target 'MobileCommonPods' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  
  
  target 'Mobile Dev' do
    end

  target 'MobileTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    nx_post_install(installer)
  end
end



"react-native": "0.68.2"
"react": "18.2.0"
Cocoapods: 1.15.2
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]
Apple M2 - MacOS 14.6.1
Help please!

It tells you the path to the file and says that it's missing, I bet it's missing, this one /Users/zzz/Documents/GitHub/project/apps/mobile/node_modules/@nrwl/react-native/nx_post_install

try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72971698/invalid-podfile-file-767-unexpected-token-at/74065592#74065592
